# Program exited with error code 04

Tags: perl, gdb

I'm trying to run a program with perl to print "A" 512 times through gdb. It returned with code 04. I started slowly going down to 511 then 510 and so on. But it still returned with code 04. Is this how it's supposed to be? If not, what am I doing wrong? Thanks for your answers.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
    char buf[256];
    if(argc == 1) 
    {
        printf("Usage: %s input\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    strcpy(buf,argv[1]);
    printf("%s", buf);
}
```

And I'm running from gdb:

```
run perl -e 'print "A" x 512'
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: We can't possibly answer this without seeing your program.

Comment: Very sorry about my mistakes. I'm new here and this is my first question.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but that still doesn't make much sense. I think I  know why your C program would exit with a status of `04`, but why are you running it under `gdb` *and* passing a perl command as its argument? Your C program would print the first argument `"perl"` and ignore the rest. Are you expect to pass 512 `'A'`s to your C program? You're not. You should get the same symptom if you just run the C program and then print the value of `$?` from your shell.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to involve either perl or gdb for this.

As of the 1989/1990 C standard, reaching the `}` at the end of `main` returns an undefined status to the environment.  (The actual status of `4` in your case is *probably* the value returned by `printf`, which is the number of characters it printed. The way you invoked the program, `argv[0]` points to the string `"perl"`, which is 4 characters long. But you absolutely should not count on that behavior.)

The 1999 standard introduced a new rule (inspired by C++): reaching the end of `main` does the equivalent of `return 0;`. But gcc by default uses the C90 standard plus GNU extensions (equivalent to `-std=gnu90`).

Add a `return 0;` to the end of your `main` function and/or compile your C program with an option that specifies a later standard, such as `-std=c99` (or `-std=gnu99` if you want to use GNU-specific extensions).

Finally, it looks like you were trying to print 512 `'A'` characters, but you were invoking your program with the arguments:

```
perl -e 'print "A" x 512'
```

That's three arguments, and your program ignores all but the first, the 4-character string `"perl"`. The remaining arguments were meant to be passed to the Perl interpreter, but you didn't invoke the Perl interpreter.

One correct way to do this would be:

```
./foo $(perl -e 'print "A" x 512')
```

where `foo` is the name of your program. But that would cause undefined behavior (possibly a program crash, or it might appear to "work" if you're unlucky), because you copy the string pointed to by `argv[1]` into an array of only 256 characters. For this simple program, that's easily avoided by not copying the string.

And your program's output doesn't end with a newline, which can cause problems. On a UNIX-like system, the program's output will likely be printed on the same line as your next shell prompt -- or the output might not be visible at all.

To see the program's exit status, type:

```
echo $?
```

(This assumes you're using bash or a similar shell.)